# Capable point and shoot for travelling?

Tags: point-and-shoot

I am going to try to keep this as open minded as I can. I use Canon bodies and lenses.

The lady friend is going to Cuba soon with her friend. Neither of them have a proper camera. (That is not attached to a phone.) The lady friend is not open to bring my kit. So I thought about getting them a point and shoot.

I would like to get them a camera that is:

- Easy to use. Less buttons, just turn on, and shoot.
- Fast AF. I've seen some terrible AF on some point and shoot.
- Can take good quality images. (Extra points for RAW.)
- Light weight. With a good optical zoom.

I wanted to get them the EOS M, it is lightweight, capable, and I can use my existing lenses, however, it seems like no body is carrying them anymore.

I did some initial research, and came across the Canon S120 with a DIGIC 6 processor, capable of doing RAW, f/1.8 at 24mm. Relatively cheap for what it is.

Can anyone suggest another point and shoot that fits the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Pentax MX-1, or the similar Olympus XZ-2 (or a cheaper XZ-1). These cameras share the same foundation (sensor & lens), but the Pentax has less controls while the Olympus has more. Both have a very fast lens for a P&S and RAW support.

Comment: Thanks for the Olympus ZX-2 suggestion. I think they will like the flip screen for those damn selfies. I didn't even think of that...